How to create a correct XPath for this site?
I have this website https://firenze.bakeca.it/annunci/tutte-le-categorie/luogo/Fucecchio/ from which I would like to gather information. The information I need is the price, the links, the description, and the square footage. I've created the following script in bash + xpath but I can't get it to work.
#!/bin/bash

# Define variables for the URL and database
sGDomain="firenze.bakeca"
sGCitta="Fucecchio"
sGTypo="luogo"
sGRegione="annunci/vendita-case"
iGPagina=1
db_file="immo.db"
max_pages=0

# Define the initial URL to get the number of pages
url="https://$sGDomain.it/$sGRegione/$sGTypo/$sGCitta/sorting/SBPRICEA/page/1/nope/true/"
echo "Processing $url"

# Obtain the starting and ending page numbers
page_info=$(xidel "$url" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0" --xpath '
  let $pageSpan := //span[@class="text-slate-700 mx-auto"]
  return string-join($pageSpan, "|")
')
echo "Page info: $page_info"

# Extract the starting and ending page numbers
page_start=$(echo "$page_info" | grep -oP 'Pagina \K\d+')
page_end=$(echo "$page_info" | grep -oP 'di \K\d+')

# Verify if the final page number is a valid number
if [[ "$page_end" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  max_pages=$page_end
else
  echo "Errore: impossibile determinare il numero di pagine finali."
  exit 1
fi

echo "Pages from $page_start to $max_pages"

# Start the loop
while (( iGPagina <= max_pages )); do

    # Construct the URL with the iGPagina variable
    url="https://$sGDomain.it/$sGRegione/$sGTypo/$sGCitta/sorting/SBPRICEA/page/$iGPagina/nope/true/"
    echo "Processing $url"
    
    # Check if the string "Nessun risultato al momento..." is present in the HTML content
    #html_content=$(wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0" --no-check-certificate -q -O - "$url")
    #if [[ $html_content == *"Nessun risultato al momento..."* ]]; then
    #    break  # Exit the loop if the string "Nessun risultato al momento..." is present
    #fi

    # Use xidel to extract the ads directly from the URL
    xidel_output=$(xidel "$url" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0" --xpath '
    //div[contains(@class, "cursor-pointer border-b relative p-3 tablet:px-0 -mx-3 mobile:mx-0 annuncio-in-elenco bg-white")] ! (
      let $price := .//span[contains(@class, "text--section text-base block")]/text(),
          $size := .//strong[contains(@class, "text-sm font-semibold") and contains(., "mq")]/text(),
          $title := .//h2[contains(@class, "text-slate-900 mb-1 break-words text-sm font-semibold tablet:text-lg tablet:leading-normal leading-tight")]/text(),
          $link := .//a[contains(@class, "annuncio__link")]/@href,
          $description := .//p[contains(@class, "text-sm mt-2 hidden tablet:block")]/text()
      return string-join(($price, $size, $title, $link, $description), "|")
    )
    ')

    # Debug output
    echo "Xidel output: $xidel_output"

    # Split xidel output and process each ad
    IFS="|" read -ra ads <<< "$xidel_output"
    for ad in "${ads[@]}"; do
        # Extract fields
        IFS="|" read -r price size title link description <<< "$ad"

        # Remove leading/trailing whitespace
        price=$(echo "$price" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')
        size=$(echo "$size" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')
        title=$(echo "$title" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')
        link=$(echo "$link" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')
        description=$(echo "$description" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')

        # Debug info
        echo "Price: $price"
        echo "Size: $size"
        echo "Title: $title"
        echo "Link: $link"
        echo "Description: $description"
        echo

        # Insert into SQLite database
        sqlite3 "$db_file" <<EOF
        INSERT INTO $sGDomain (price, size, title, link, description)
        VALUES ('$price', '$size', '$title', '$link', '$description');
EOF
    done

    # Increment the iGPagina variable for the next iteration
    ((iGPagina++))
done
 

I believe the xpath is unable to find [the elements] and gives me the following error.
Error:
err:XPTY0004: Invalid types for function contains#2.
Got: (attribute class {"{ '!bg-slate-50': isDisabled }"}, attribute class {"px-4 w-full inline-flex desktop:h-full items-center gap-2 !border-solid !border !border-slate-500/40 rounded bg-white text-slate-700 focus-within:shadow focus-within:!border-[var(--section-color)] !bg-slate-50"}), "cursor-pointer border-b relative p-3 tablet:px-0 -mx-3 mobile:mx-0 annuncio-in-elenco bg-white"
Expected: (string?, string?) as boolean
in pxp:contains(TXQTermNodeMatcher, TXQTermConstant)

in line 1 column 7
//div[contains(@class, "cursor-pointer border-b relative p-3 tablet:px-0 -mx-3 mobile:mx-0 annuncio-in-elenco bg-white")] ! (
      ^^^^^^^^^^  error occurs around here

Possible backtrace:
  $00000000004FBFDB: perhaps Q{http://expath.org/ns/file}temp-dir + 589035 ? but unlikely
  $0000000000520B60: perhaps TXQTermBinaryOp + 3808 ? but unlikely

Call xidel with --trace-stack to get an actual backtrace
Xidel output: 

I have tested several xpaths without success. I also tried downloading the webpage (I know it's not good practice) and then verifying it on the page with xpath, but I can't download it with wget, curl, or even Firefox. So, if anyone can lend me a hand...

To assist you, we need sample input XML data in the question. Also explaining what is the expected output from the XPATH query. Also sample of the expected output from XPATH query.

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question appropriately.

@Reino is  just reproducible , remove sqlite part and  work it
